# Catel custom View creation

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I would like to create custom window and show it without `IUIvisualizerService` with Catel.

The problem is: When I create a window, bind ViewModel to it, seems like View does not react on properties changes.

I have done following:

```
var photo = new Photo();
NewPhotoWindow newPhotoWindow = new NewPhotoWindow();
var viewModel = new NewPhotoWindowViewModel(photo);
newPhotoWindow.DataContext = viewModel;

newPhotoWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Is there a way to create it via some kind of ViewLocator?

I have tried with `TypeFactory`, but this does not allow me to put photo as a model for my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually doing the ViewModel creation in Catel. It's all done for you automatically.

This should be sufficient:

```
uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog<NewPhotoWindow>();
```

This will automatically:

1. Resolve the VM that belongs to NewPhotoWindow (NewPhotoWindowViewModel or NewPhotoViewModel).
2. Instantiate the VM using IViewModelFactory
3. Create the window and set the vm to it

Comment: Yes I know but it has one limitation. It does not allow me to store window reference and  I need it.

Comment: Then you probably need to implement your own IUIVisualizerService (or derive from the existing and override the right methods) that allows you to do something with the window that you need to do with it.

Why do you need access to the window?

Comment: I would like to show it (bring to front) on certain actions